# Website returning spoofed result/404 while scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the following [site](https://legitquest.com/Home/GetCaseDetails?searchType=citation&publisher=AIR%201950%20SC%201#). I tried using `request.get` and parsed with Beautiful Soup, but it does not return the same result as to when viewed using a browser. I also directly calling the endpoint they were using but that returns a 404 error. I have tried using headers, but that has not solved it. How do I solve it?

Here is the code, I used:

```py
import requests
import BeautifulSoup

headers = headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'}

URL = 'url'
x = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The above code does return output, but it does not have the same content as the website, that is the link to a article that appears

Comment: Do share what you have tried and not a link to image.

Comment: Do you want to get the url of the result?

Comment: No, just the heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used ajax to load the page.I found the API.
All the url could be:

```
url = "https://legitquest.com/Search/GetResultBySelectedSearchResult?caseText=AIR+1950+SC+1&type=citation&filter=&sortBy=1&formattedCitation=AIR+1950+SC+1&removeFilter=&filterValueList=&_={}".format(str(time.time()).replace(".","")[:-4])
```

[image]

But due to some reasons, it also couldn't crawl the page.(This page use a strict rule to prevent crawl)

Even I used the right url,it also couldn't get it:

[image]

---

Strongly recommend you use `selenium`.It will be easier.

---

I get it:

```
import requests
import time

headers = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
url = 'https://legitquest.com/Search/GetResultBySelectedSearchResult?caseText=AIR+1950+SC+1&type=citation&filter=&sortBy=1&formattedCitation=AIR+1950+SC+1&removeFilter=&filterValueList=&_={}'.format(str(time.time()).replace(".","")[:-4])
x = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(x.json()["CaseDetails"][0]["LinkText"])
```

Result:

```
Sheth Maneklal Mansukhbhai V. Messrs. Hormusji Jamshedji Ginwallaand Sons
```

---

The json format:

```
{
    'filterList': '',
    'filterValueList': '',
    'caseText': 'AIR 1950 SC 1',
    'currentpage': 1,
    'CaseCount': 1,
    'openPopup': False,
    'UserId': '',
    'IsSubscribed': False,
    'IsMobileDevice': False,
    'CaseDetails': [{
        'LinkText': 'Sheth Maneklal Mansukhbhai V. Messrs. Hormusji Jamshedji Ginwallaand Sons',
        'PartyName': 'sheth-maneklal-mansukhbhai-vs-messrs.-hormusji-jamshedji-ginwallaand-sons',
        'SearchString': None,
        'CaseId': 21763,
        'EncryptedId': '1EBBB',
        'CourtName': 'Supreme Court Of India',
        'Id': 125883,
        'CourtId': 1,
        'CaseType': None,
        'HeadNotes': None,
        'Judges': "HON'BLE MR. JUSTICE M.C. MAHAJAN<BR />HON'BLE MR. JUSTICE SAIYID FAZAL ALI<BR />HON'BLE MR. JUSTICE B.K. MUKHERJEA",
        'DateOfJudgment': '21-03-1950',
        'Judgment': None,
        'OrderByDateTime': '/Date(-624326400000)/',
        'CaseNo': None,
        'Advocates': None,
        'CitationText': '',
        'CitatedCount': 0,
        'CopyText': None,
        'AlternativeCitation': '(1950) SCR 75 ; AIR 1950 SC 1 ; 1950 SCJ 317 ; (1950) 63 LW 495',
        'Petitioner': None,
        'Responder': None,
        'Citation': None,
        'Question': None,
        'HighlightedText': '',
        'IsFoundText': True,
        'IsOverruledExist': False,
        'IsDistinguishedExist': False,
        'IsOtherStatusExist': True,
        'OtherStatusImgUrl': 'https://www.legitquest.com/Content/themes/treatment/referred.svg',
        'OverruledImgUrl': None,
        'DistinguishedImgUrl': None,
        'BookmarkId': 0,
        'Chart': None,
        'CaseCitedCount': None,
        'SnapShot': None
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Doing This :

```
url = 'https://legitquest.com/Home/GetCaseDetails?searchType=citation&publisher=AIR%201950%20SC%201'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36'}
page_html = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print("Status Code : ")
print(page_html.status_code)
page_soup = soup(page_html.content,features="lxml")
```

I got this result which you require

[image]

Comment: No. It's just returning an empty list. Also, I need the link to the article which comes up when searched with that URL.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think they may be spoofing the results?

Comment: It's their in front of you the status code you can then search for elements you need... If you only need Links you may search for extention tools they can help you :)

Comment: Hey! 
I believe it has not returned. Can you check whether you are getting the following article name when you retrieve the content: ```Sheth Maneklal Mansukhbhai V. Messrs. Hormusji Jamshedji Ginwallaand Sons.
```
It is returning a 200, but that does not mean it is correct.